# Connenting dialogflow to a GraphQL database and sending query

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on a Dialogflow part of a project.Some body else created the database part of project in GraphQL and now I want to connect DialogFlow intents to this database,send query and get response.As I have no idea about it and I have only the URL of database, can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow does not provide any direct integration with backend systems except through a straightforward webhook protocol. You're responsible for building the bridge between that protocol and however you extract the data from your database - using GraphQL in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.Do you have any clear example of "building the bridge between that protocol and however you extract the data from your database" ? (any other database)